# What is the U Area equivalent data structure in Linux?

Tags: linux, unix

We have U Area in UNIX which holds the information related to a process. What is the data structure analogous to U Area, in Linux?

Also, is it possible to view the contents held by U Area in UNIX ( and Linux also )?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux, the contents of the U area are stored in a [task_struct](http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ds/ds.html) with the rest of the process information.

To my knowledge, it can only be accessed through the [proc](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) filesystem.